# Removing [ ] in single json object

Tags: php, json

I have following code which generate json object.

```
$res=  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` where `id`='$_id' ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) 
{
     $jsonData[] = $row;          
}
$data = json_encode($jsonData);
echo $data;
```

Its output is like this (This is json object).

```
[
   {
       "id": "11",
       "username": "tezt69",
       "insta_id": "1003817812",
       "access_token": "1003817812.9896620.aa4bbfe407f04db8b69ffff0dda60685",
       "profile_pic": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg",
       "coins": "9",
       "level": "1",
       "experience_pts": "0",
       "instamena": "0",
       "critical_chance": "0",
       "free_chance": "0",
       "instamena_timer": "0",
       "pause_time": "0",
       "is_promotion": "1",
       "auto_promotion": "0",
       "exp_next_level": "10",
       "media": "0",
       "follows": "0",
       "followed_by": "0",
       "added-on": "2014-05-24 02:23:09"
   }
]
```

Now I want to remove `[ ]` so that it parse in single loop.

Comment: Why not simply use `$data[0]`?

Comment: o ho .might be you are right let me try this i think it works

Comment: I will support @Amal's comment, what happens if somehow you have more than one row in database?

Comment: @bansi actually i fetch only one result whenever i query thats way its works fine

Comment: @waleed: If you're only fetching one record, why do you have a `while` loop at all? Just do: `$row = mysql_fetch_array($res); echo json_encode($row);`.

Comment: you are right.ok i remove while loop
(actually i code a lot in this project so doing in copy,paste i forget to remove while loop)

Comment: instead of $data[0], as it may be an 'associative array' or the first index may not be zero. I would use: current($data). To find out what the index is then i use: key($data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options available to you.

```
$res=  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` where `id`='$_id' ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    $jsonData = $row;
}
$data = json_encode($jsonData);
echo $data;
```

OR

```
$res=  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` where `id`='$_id' ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    $jsonData[] = json_encode($row);
}
echo $jsonData[0];
```

OR

```
$res=  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` where `id`='$_id' ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    $jsonData[] = json_encode($row);
}
$data = $jsonData[0]
echo $data;
```